# Build Pipeline Keeps on Asking to Approve Deployment Group

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a build pipeline created in Azure DevOps that has the following stages:

- Build application
- Deploy application to DEV
- Deploy application to TST

```
# cicd.yml
stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: 'Build API Application'
  jobs:
  - template: templates/build-template.yml

- stage: DEV_Deployment
  displayName: 'Deploy Application to the DEV Environment'
  variables: 
  - group: 'Variable Group DEV'
  dependsOn: Build
  condition: succeeded()
  jobs:
  - template: templates/deployment-template.yml
    parameters:
      vmImage: '$(vmImage)'
      environment: 'development'
      serviceConnection: $(serviceConnection)
      webAppName: $(webApiName)

- stage: TST_Deployment
  displayName: 'Deploy Application to the TST Environment'
  variables: 
  - group: 'Variable Group TEST'
  dependsOn: DEV_Deployment
  condition: succeeded()
  jobs:
  - template: templates/deployment-template.yml
    parameters:
      vmImage: '$(vmImage)'
      environment: 'test'
      serviceConnection: $(serviceConnection)
      webAppName: $(webApiName)
```

Everytime I run this pipeline, it asks for my approval to use the **Variable Group TEST** variable group, and it asks it for every stage (build, dev deployment, and tst deployment). What's strange is that my build and dev deployment stages do not even use this variable group. What could be causing this issue?

Comment: Check whether if this pipeline has been added into Pipeline permissions in Variable Group TEST variable group.

Comment: Pamoda, I have added the pipeline in the Pipeline permissions of the Variable Group TEST variable group, but I am still being asked for approval.

Comment: @JoshMonreal can you please add `deployment-template.yml` and `build-template.yml` in your question as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As seen in [Azure/Azure DevOps/Azure Pipelines/Add & use variable groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/variable-groups?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml):

> Secret variables in Variables groups are [protected resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/security/resources?view=azure-devops).
>
> You can add combinations of **approvals**, checks, and pipeline permissions to limit access to secret variables in a variable group. Access to non-secret variables is not limited by approvals, checks, and pipeline permissions.

So make sure there is no secret variable involved here: even if the variable is not used, an approval might still be required in that case.